# Custom TextView cuts off using wrap_content

Tags: java, android, textview

I created a custom TextView, in order to add a new font:

```
 public class CustomTextView  extends TextView{

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setTypeface(SplashActivity.SECRET_CODE_TYPEFACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setTypeface(SplashActivity.SECRET_CODE_TYPEFACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context){
        super(context);
        setTypeface(SplashActivity.SECRET_CODE_TYPEFACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Now, when I use this TextView, the text is cut off:
[image: Result]

And here is my XML:

```
<com.whereisthemonkey.sqlsheetmanager.Graphics.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="56sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

Add padding into your text view,as shown below:

```
<com.whereisthemonkey.sqlsheetmanager.Graphics.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textSize="56sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it works even better when using padding-bottom and padding-top